# DynamoDB And RDS Mysql

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I am working on Proof of Concept in which we are getting Live Data streams from Kinesis and we want to save it in DynamoDB.

But we have the lookup tables data in RDS (Mysql) instances as we would require to perform join operations with lookup tables.

Questions:

1. should we Migrate the lookup tables data in DynamoDB through AWS DMS Or any other approach will be suitable.
2. Is DynamoDB more suitable for join operations with lookup tables?
3. Can we use PartiQL in DynamoDB to query data and perform join operations with lookup tables?

Comment: How are you going to store the steam into the dynomodb?  Are you running a separate service to consume the stream and store it to dynamodb ?

Comment: Hi Amith , Yes Lambda code will poll the Kinesis stream and ingest data into DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynomoDB streams to replicate data to any other application.
Please have a look here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Further more, DynomoDB is not suitable for Join operations.